# React slick doesn't loop slides if slidesToShow is equal to the total slides

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I need a carousel that will autoplay and loop through items infinitely.

The react slick component doesn't slide through to the first elements if slidesToShow is equal to slide number. It just loops through current items. The carousel doesn't slide.

I saw there are some issues in the slick slider too ([Slick Slider Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037680/slick-slider-not-loading-slides-if-slidestoshow-is-equal-to-the-total-slides)).

Does anyone have any solution to fix this in React?

Here is the CodeSandbox example to check: [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-kdmxg?file=/src/index.js:429-441)