# Slick slider not showing arrows if slidesToShow is equal to the total slides

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I wanted to show the arrows but when slidesToShow is equal to the total slides
the arrows is not showing even the infinite is set to true, is there a way to show the arrows when slidesToShow is equal to the total slides or is it expected behavior of the slider?

I have check this thread ( [Slick slider not loading slides if slidesToShow is equal to the total slides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037680/slick-slider-not-loading-slides-if-slidestoshow-is-equal-to-the-total-slides) ) it seems that the solution requires to change the core file of the library. Is there any way we don't change the core file.

Below is the codepen
https://codepen.io/davecar21/pen/RwovWvB

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').slick({
     infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  variableWidth: true,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 720,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        infinite: true
      }
    }],
  arrow: true
  });
});
```

Comment: It's the expected behavior. Otherwise you could have a single slide slick with arrows. You could fake it out by doubling up your slides and choosing infinite.

Comment: I see so the only way would be modifying the library code file to be able to show the arrows then right?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to if there is nothing that  happens when they're clicked.

Comment: If you're interested in a bandaid, I can put one as the answer

Comment: So here's the deal, the scenario is that when we wanted to show the 3rd image as partial it will looks off as the arrow is not showing and the 3rd image will be left off half shown or partially shown. Please check the link ( https://codepen.io/davecar21/pen/RwovWvB ) to see the scenario.